# Regex Extract in Google Docs for capturing the end of variable strings

Tags: regex, string, google-docs

In Google Docs, if I have a series of strings like "Something.Here.Search.Term.Chicago", where the last component after "Term." can be anything.

How do I use regex extract to only capture what comes after "Term."?

Note that the length of the string varies before Term so I can't use Left or Right and position since it's always different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess about with capturing groups and you know the component you want is the substring between the last `.` and the end of the string, you could use

```
[^.]+$
```

Comment: That would work except I didn't mention there's a lot of Strings that aren't search terms with the same . stucture that I want to ignore.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I tried your expression and it works perfectly except it captures everything after the last . wether or not it's a search term. So I have get this working for only terms after the last . preceded by "Term" only.

Comment: Google Docs didn't like that. Calling it an invalid invalid perl operator: (?<  So I guess I was wrong. It doesn't support look behinds?

Comment: @gdilla I don't think it supports look-behinds, so you will have to use a capturing group e.g. `Term\.(\S+)`. I am now away from the computer...

Comment: Woot, that works. I modified it to "Term\.(.+)" because some of the trailing terms are multiple words with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a positive look-behind as well, to avoid having to capture with groups:

```
/(?<=Term\.).*/
```

Though depending on the language you are implementing this with, it may not support look-behinds (namely JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Google Docs, but normally in regular expressions, you would do

```
"Something\.Here\.Search\.Term\.(.*)"
```

The `()` means capture and remember the pattern within.  In this case `.*` means everything.  You can usually access the pattern as `$1`, etc. in Javascript.

See [Examples of Regular Expressions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YFyOFSm7P4pssBMY7qTrWinz2SDMZW1KUnkmePDORS0/preview?pli=1)

Comment: I think the latest edit to this added extra escape characters to the periods. Those should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me using you sample data:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; ".*Term.(.*)" ; "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a "look-ahead" expression `(?=)`, 
then something repeated followed by a word boundary?

Something like this:

```
(?=Term\\.).*\W
```